# Retrurning extra fields using the facebook search API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook graph API to search for all public business within a certain range based on location. I want to return some extra fields, specifically the 'hours of business' but can't see how I can do this? 
`search?q=&type=place&center=-33.8650,151.2094&distance=5000'
I realize you can add extra fields in the graph API tool but that is only for things that you have a connection to. Whereas I want to query all 'public' businesses therefore it looks like I'm restricted to use the search functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fields parameter to specify fields you want to see...  `search?q=&type=place&center=-33.8650,151.2094&distance=5000&fields=hours`